# 2D face tracking on Spark AR

Tags: javascript, canvas, spark-ar-studio

I've been trying to make the face texture in a 2D canvas/plane move only along the X/Y axis, following the movements of the face without rotating, with the 2D background camera texture reflected accurately on top. Right now, when I connect the canvas to the face tracker I'm getting distorted scale, and the 2D plane rotates in 3D space. See below for the current canvas/camera texture/face tracker set-up. Manual scaling results in poor tracking.

Here is my code:

```
const FaceTracking = require('FaceTracking')
const Scene = require('Scene')

export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

// Locate the plane in the Scene
// Enable async/await in JS [part 1]
(async function () {
  const [plane] = await Promise.all([
    Scene.root.findFirst('blur_plane')
  ])

  // Store a reference to a detected face
  const face = FaceTracking.face(0)

  // To access scene objects
  const planeTransform = plane.transform
  const faceTransform = face.cameraTransform
  // const blurCanvas = Scene.root.find('canvas0');

  // To access class properties
  planeTransform.rotationX = faceTransform[0]
  planeTransform.rotationY = faceTransform[0]
  planeTransform.rotationZ = faceTransform[0]
})()
```

This is the current look:
[image: current canvas/camera texture and face tracker set-up]
I want the 375x667px canvas to look exactly like the camera layer beneath it, so that without adjustments to the camera texture the layer would not be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Facebook has an example that deals with 2D movement but not scale:
https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/facetrackingmodule